# How to read others languages with tesseract on C#

Tags: tesseract

I'm trying to run tesseract on c #.
The program works well on English language  'ocr.Init(@"C:\Program Files\Tesseract-OCR\tessdata", "eng", false);'
If I try to change the language from "eng" to "ita", the program generates an error and does not work.
The directory ".../tessdata" contains  "ita.traineddata" and others ita. files.
I use the library tessnet2.dll.

Thanks,
Alessandro.

Answer (score 0):

You have used an incompatible (3.0x) data version. Try [tesseract-2.00.ita.tar.gz](http://code.google.com/p/tesseract-ocr/downloads/list).